Electron js app is not created successfully
electron-builder  version=24.13.3 os=10.0.22631
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=keytar@7.9.0, sqlite3@5.1.7 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • install prebuilt binary  name=keytar version=7.9.0 platform=win32 arch=x64 napi=
  • install prebuilt binary  name=sqlite3 version=5.1.7 platform=win32 arch=x64 napi=
  • build native dependency from sources  name=sqlite3
                                          version=5.1.7
                                          platform=win32
                                          arch=x64
                                          napi=
reason=prebuild-install failed with error (run with env DEBUG=electron-builder to get more information)
                                          error=prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 7.1.2
    prebuild-install warn This package does not support N-API version 36
    prebuild-install warn install prebuilt binaries enforced with --force!
    prebuild-install warn install prebuilt binaries may be out of date!
    prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds\sqlite3-v5.1.7-napi-v36-win32-x64.tar.gz
   

`
I face this error while i'm creating build for electron js project , but it not created successfully i'm facing this error **So any idea what to do **

npm uninstall sqlite3 --force 
npm install -E sqlite3@5.1.6

this works
